# how display a gray image in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I have an image and I want to convert that image into gray. After that, I tried to display that gray image in GUI but it became exactly look like a rainbow. How can I display a gray image in GUI? I tried the below code but it does not work. Please help

```
X = imread('j3.jpg');
X=rgb2gray(X);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(X)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error using matlab.ui.Figure/set
While setting the 'Colormap' property of 'Figure':
Value must be either:
an Mx3 array of type single or double in the range [0 1]
an Mx3 array of type uint8

Error in images.internal.basicImageDisplay (line 71)
    set(fig_handle, 'Colormap', map);

Error in imshow (line 293)
  hh = images.internal.basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...

Error in gray>pushbutton1_Callback (line 83)
imshow(X)

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in gray (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)gray('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

What is the issue and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have named your GUI `gray.m` which conflicts with the builtin `gray` function which provides the grayscale colormap (the default for `imshow`). As a result, when MATLAB tries to create the grayscale colormap (`colormap(gray)`), it instead calls your GUI and the output is not what `colormap` is expecting, resulting in the error that you've shown.

You will need to rename your GUI to something else and you should have no issues.